# How to run the class file that is in another machine?

Tags: java, sockets

Is it possible to run class file which is on different system?

For instance,

I have 2 machines (server and client) and there are 2 java class files SocketServer.class and SocketClient.class in respective machines.

I need to run SocketClient.class from server machine to make connection establish between server and client. (Note: I should not run SocketClient.class manually)

Please advice?

Thanks in advance.

-Sithik

Comment: By default this is not allowed.  You must set something up before it can work - what is possible?

Comment: Do you have any idea what can be done?

Comment: Plenty.  Question is what is available to you?  Given your current level of expertise, you may want to look into how you can get a command prompt remotely and run "java .... SocketClient" in that.

Comment: There are many ways a client and server can communicate: Telnet, FTP, HTTP, etc. To start with, you need to pick a transport layer, and possibly pick a communication protocol (like SOAP) that uses that layer.

Comment: There is no problem with Socket connection. I am able to transfer data between server machine and client machine. What I don't know is, how to invoke SocketClient.class file from SocketServer.class file.Is it possible to invoke remotely?

Answer (score -1):

It is my understanding that the client generally makes the connection to the server to access resources on the server. In the past I have used an API to access resources on the server. Essentially I am not running the classes from the server directly I am using the API as a form of abstraction in order to handle the communication between the resources on the client side and server side.

I also mainly implement the Factory Design Pattern which may help you here.
http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/

Ultimately your application should make requests of a server first and once a connection is established then the server will provide a response.

Comment: There is no problem with Socket connection. I am able to transfer data between server machine and client machine. What I don't know is, how to invoke SocketClient.class file from SocketServer.class file.Is it possible to invoke remotely?